# Assertion Error: 1 == 0 for MongoDB deleteOne Command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to workout some of the CRUD operations for a MongoDB/NodeJS/Express application I'm working on, and I'm having difficult with the `deleteOne` command, presumably because it's not recognizing my query, although I don't know why.

I lifted the mongoDB code from the [NodeJS driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/crud/), and my code block looks like this:

**DELETE REQUEST:**

```
router.delete('/formula-list/:id', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db.collection('formulas');
  var id = req.params.id;
  var query = { "_id": id };
  db.deleteOne(query, function(err, r){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.equal(1, r.deletedCount);
    db.close();
  });
  res.end();
});
```

When I run this it returns the error `AssertionError: 1 == 0`, which I take to mean that the program doesn't have a document to delete.

However, if I do a `console.log(req.params.id)` I get `587f6ff4824d0a085c2b57bf`, which is an _id for a document in my database:

[image: MongoDB document]

`console.log(db)` returns the following:

**console.log(db):**

```
{ s:
 { pkFactory:
  { [Function: ObjectID]
    index: 858167,
    createPk: [Function: createPk],
    createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
    createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString],
    isValid: [Function: isValid],
    ObjectID: [Circular],
    ObjectId: [Circular] },
 db:
  EventEmitter {
    domain: null,
    _events: {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    s: [Object],
    serverConfig: [Getter],
    bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
    databaseName: [Getter] },
 topology:
  EventEmitter {
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    clientInfo: [Object],
    s: [Object] },
 dbName: 'formulas',
 options: { promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise], readConcern: undefined },
 namespace: 'formulas.formulas',
 readPreference:
  { _type: 'ReadPreference',
    mode: 'primary',
    tags: undefined,
    options: undefined },
 slaveOk: true,
 serializeFunctions: undefined,
 raw: undefined,
 promoteLongs: undefined,
 promoteValues: undefined,
 promoteBuffers: undefined,
 internalHint: null,
 collectionHint: null,
 name: 'formulas',
 promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
 readConcern: undefined } }
```

I take this to mean that the Mongo collection itself is also being recognized since it's not returning `undefined`.

Any advice on what I'm getting wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to cast the `req.params.id` to an ObjectId type first i.e. `var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID; var id = new ObjectID(req.params.id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native `mongodb` library needs `_id` to be `ObjectId`

End result would look more-less like this:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

// Other code lines

router.delete('/formula-list/:id', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db.collection('formulas');
  var query = { "_id": new mongo.ObjectId(req.params.id) };
  db.deleteOne(query, function(err, r){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.equal(1, r.deletedCount);
    db.close();
  });
  res.end();
});
```