# task timeout error in AWS Lambda and mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aws-lambda

```
...
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false; //keeps mongoose connection active
  /*
        init values
    */
  var a = event.a,
    b = event.b,
    c = event.c,
    d = event.d,
    e = event.e;

  var output = {
    //TODO look into SSMS
    dialogAction: {
      type: "Close",
      fulfillmentState: "Fulfilled",
      message: {
        contentType: "PlainText",
        content: "Record for " + a + " successfully updated."
      }
    }
  }; //output
  // Use connect method to connect to the server
  console.log(event);
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection("a");
    collection.updateOne(
      { a: a },
      { $set: { b: b } },
      { $set: { c: c } },
      { $set: { d: d } },
      { $set: { e: e } },
      function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        assert.equal(1, result.result.n);
        console.log("Updated the document for " + a);
        callback(result);
      }
    );
  });
};
...
```

```
lambda-local -l index.js -h handler -e holiq.js
```

There is no error in holiq.js
event output correctly and mongodb connect successfully but

> error: End - Error:
>   `error: {
>           "errorMessage": "Task timed out after 5.00 seconds",
>           "errorType": "TimeoutError",
>           "stackTrace": [
>                   "Context.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lambda-local/lib/context.js:127:9)",
>                   "ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)",
>                   "tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)",
>                   "listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)",
>                   "Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)"
>           ]
>   }`

time out error occured
Please help me!~

Answer (score 1):

I think only one `$set` needs to be used for updating

```
collection.updateOne(
      { a: a },
      { $set: { b: b,e: e, c: c, d: d } },
      function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        assert.equal(1, result.modifiedCount)
        console.log("Updated the document for " + a);
        callback(result);
      }
    );
```

Increase lambda execution time to `10 secs` to see if its time out problem or code execution error.

Comment: Thank you Amol B Jamkar.
Another error occur now.
...node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:123
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 1 == 0

Comment: I think mongo cannot find `a` to update the document. Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205665/assertion-error-1-0-for-mongodb-deleteone-command, Please check your database first.

Comment: I checked my database and there is column that I finding.

Comment: `upadateOne` returns `{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }` as per reference document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/. In your case check should be  `assert.equal(1, result.result.modifiedCount);`  or `assert.equal(1, result.modifiedCount);`

Comment: In my case it returns modifiedCount : 0
So I use mongoose and mongoose works well.
Anyway, Thanks for your help Amol B Jamkar